# My C# program is using Excessive Memory (BinaryReader to buffer)

Tags: c#, arrays, file, io, filestream

My program is using excessive memory. I am trying to read the first 512 bytes of a program and store them in memory. I believe it should only use 512 bytes of memory, but for some reason, it is using 1GB.

```
BinaryReader reader;
byte[] buffer = new byte[0];

foreach (IStorageDevice device in Devices)
{
    reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(device.Location, FileMode.Open));
    buffer = reader.ReadBytes(512);
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

There was only one `StorageDevice` in the test I did, so it is only loading one file.

I can't seem to find the reason why it is using so much memory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Devices` is a `List` of `IStorageDevice`s. A storage device is just a class with a string object which is the path to the file that is read (at the moment it is a .bin file on my desktop)

```
public class ROM : IStorageDevice
{
    public string Location { get; set; }

     public ROM(string Location)
     {
         this.Location = Location;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You never close the file handler?

Comment: I do close the file.

Comment: When? Binary reader is disposable but you never dispose

Comment: I forgot to copy that into the question, but it was there in my program. I'll edit it now.

Comment: what makes you think this is causing a 1GiB read? `File.Open` is a `Stream`; it doesn't load the entire file - so even if you *did* forget to dispose it, it isn't going to do much (except lock the file); so again: what makes you think that *this* is the cause?

Comment: I can tell you exactly the line that is causing it because I put in breakpoints. It is the buffer = reader.ReadeBytes(512); The memory spikes on that line as I step through.

Comment: There is something more going on than the code you are showing here. I used the path to a 7+ GB file using this code and my memory usage went up by less than a MB. Are you sure you don't have a loop which reads the entire file, and the file is a GiB in size?

Comment: Heretic Monkey, it must have been because I wasn't disposing the BinaryReader properly because my memory usage doesn't go past 20MB. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose of your resources.  That's what using does.  The stream will be disposed when the using block is exited.

Try something like this:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

    foreach (IStorageDevice device in Devices)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(device.Location))
        {
            // Read 512 bytes into buffer if possible.  
            var readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 512);
            StoreData(buffer, readCount); // A method you write to store the data
        }
    }
```

Comment: That has cut my memory usage in half, it uses around 583MB now.

Comment: Comment out the whole using statement and see what that does.  Does that foreach loop consume memory?

Comment: At the moment, the foreach loop only has one object in it. It is a string that stores a directory.

Comment: What does the class that defines Devices look like.  Can you include that in your question?

Comment: Oh, and how many items are in Devices?  Where you able to see how much is consumed by just enumerating Devices?

Comment: There is only one item currently. I added another item, to test it, and the memory usage stayed the same.

Comment: How are you determining the amount of memory being used?  Where are you looking?  Could you just be loading a lot of assemblies into memory while it runs?

Comment: Ah, your answer does work, there was 583MB in another part of my program that I didn't account for. It must have been me needing to properly dispose the BinaryReader. Thank you.

Comment: @ReeceNoone The best way you can thank Jim is to take a few seconds to read [What to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)